# ¿Como abrir cualquier aplicación en vista emergente por código?

Tags: android, android-studio, vistas, packages

Estoy en la realización de una aplicación y necesito buscar dentro del celular todas las aplicaciones existentes y al dar click en una que se abra en vista emergente como lo muestra la imagen.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Con el siguiente código llamo puedo abrir una aplicación mediante el nombre de su Package pero la pregunta es como abrir dicha aplicación en vista emergente?

```
Intent launchIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("Package");
startActivity(launchIntent);
```

Les agradezco la ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

En este caso podrìas tu mismo construir la pantalla donde muestras las aplicaciones:

#### Android, obtener aplicaciones instaladas en dispositivo

```
Intent mainIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
mainIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
List<ResolveInfo> listaAppsInstaladas = getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities( mainIntent, 0);

for(ResolveInfo r: listaAppsInstaladas){
    Log.i(TAG, " App nombre: " + r.activityInfo.name + " , package name: " +r.activityInfo.packageName);
}
```

al obtener una lista de Apps, puedes usar el package name para abrir la aplicaciòn que desees:

```
Intent launchIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("Package");
startActivity(launchIntent);
```